# How to eliminate global variables -- common patterns

Tags: javascript

I have fallen into a 'comfort' zone in my code and use this pattern a lot but I realize it isn't the best practice, how can I go about creating this function without relying on a global variable?

```
  var map;
  function initialize_gmaps() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.705786,-80.007672);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
    // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng,map: map,title:"Hello World!"});
  }
```

As you can see `var map` is a global variable.  Is it best practice to return the 'map' var whenever I need to reference map? Is there a better pattern for this? Here is what I am thinking...

```
      function initialize_gmaps() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.705786,-80.007672);
        var map;
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        return map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
        // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng,map: map,title:"Hello World!"});
      }
```

The main problem I see with this pattern is that I am re-assigning `var map` every time I call function initialize_gmaps() which isn't optimal.

What is a better pattern for this scenario? Is there a name for this type of pattern in JS, I imagine this is a common problem.

Comment: "I am re-assigning var map every time I call function initialize_gmaps() which isn't optimal." What does this mean?

Comment: If you are worried about muddying the global namespace then you can wrap all of your code in an IIFE to create your own private scope.

Comment: Every time I call the function, I am 're creating var map', I am initializing it at the top of the function (var map;) and then assigning and returning it again, opposed to just referencing the global 'map' variable after intialize_gmaps() one time.

Comment: Why do you think that is problematic? You're creating a local function variable.

Comment: Maybe I have a misunderstanding of what is happening then. Scenario A gives me a reference to the global map var. After Scenario A is run one time, I now never have to run the function again.  In Scenario B, whenever I want reference var map, or use var map, I need to run a function every time to gain access to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `map` variable in `initalize_gmaps()`.  It's a temporary local variable that simply isn't needed.  You can just do this:

```
  function initialize_gmaps() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.705786,-80.007672),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  }
```

---

In fact, even the `mapOptions` variable isn't needed either, though I can see a reason to use it just for readability (personal preference).  But, you could even do this:

```
  function initialize_gmaps() {
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.705786,-80.007672),
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  }
```

There are many useful reasons to use local variables, but a one-time use variable like your `map` variable that you are just immediately assigning and returning really has no utility and just creates a bit of extra work for the interpeter.

---

You may also analyze why you're recreating the map multiple times?  Perhaps it would be better to just save the initial map you create and use that one repeatedly rather than creating a new one each time.  You'd have to show much more context of your code (how and where the returned map object is used) for us to advise further on that topic.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense.  I am looking over my code now and seeing how often I have to reference the global object. Thanks for all the input so far, I'm still reading all of these and absorbing the content, thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it best practice to return the 'map'

Yes. There's not need for a local `map` variable in the `initialize_gmaps` function though. Just do

```
return new google.maps.Map(…);
```

> I am re-assigning var map every time I call function initialize_gmaps()

Why would you initialize the map multiple times?

You should make a local variable for the map in the section where you're adding the markers to the map. This could look like

```
$(function() { // assuming jQuery
    var map = initialize_gmaps();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng,
                                         map: map,
                                         title: "Hello World!"});
    …
});
```